# Wordpress OnTheGo Theme #content conflict

Tags: wordpress

I'm having trouble figuring out how to fix a conflict I am experiencing with the wordpress theme OnTheGo. Please look at the following page on my website: http://www.caferacermag.com/product/flat-out-flyin-t/ As you can see, my header is showing up twice. I know it has something to do with the #content tag in the style sheet but I have no idea how to fix it. Can someone please show me how to fix this? Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="contentwrap">
<div id="content">
<div></div>
<div>
<div id="main-area" class="clearfix">
<div id="container">  
<div id="content" role="main">  // <== change id="content" to something else
 ---
------

---------------------
```

you have `<div id="content ">` inside `<div id="content ">` and backgroung image is given to that id thats why its appearing twice.. change id of inner div

Comment: Thanks so much wordpressor!! You saved me so many headaches. I was able to change the header tag to make it work.